# How do I make sure my service is registered before Startup.cs is executed in a dot net core app?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, program-entry-point, startup

I am working with a dot net core 3.1 console app, that has a Startup.cs class where services are registered.

Any thoughts on how you would make a service initialised in `Program.cs` of a dot net Core console project, available all throughout the project (for example in controllers) with the values given in `Program.cs`?

The service needs to have 2 implementations based on a flag in `appsettings.json`

I need to initiate/instantiate the service in `Program.cs` (because I use the Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) part from Program.cs to set up some elements needed for the service). But my service is registered in `Startup`, which is executed after `Program.cs`, so I get an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

obviously because in Program.cs I have: `private readonly static IServiceA _serviceA;`

but I am only registering it later in `Startup.cs` (after using it): services.AddSingleton(); (in ConfigureServices)

Here is the Program.cs in full:

```
public static class Program
    {
        private readonly static IStoreService _storeService;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUnityServiceProvider()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
                {
                    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
                    var keyVaultUrl = string.Format("https://{0}.vault.azure.net/", configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").GetSection("VaultName").Value);

                    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

                    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                            azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                    builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultUrl, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

                    PopulateServiceStore(keyVaultUrl, keyVaultClient);
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

        private static void PopulateServiceStore(string keyVaultUrl, KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient)
        {
            var myDbConnection= Task.Run(async () => await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl, "DatabasePassword")).Result.Value;
            _storeService.DbConnection = myDbConnection; // breaks at this line because service is not registered (normally happens in Startup.cs which is executed later)

        }
    }
```

Update:
I have thought of adding this in Main:

```
           .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IKeyStoreService,
                          KeyVaultService>();
            })
```

just before `.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => ...`

but inside ConfigureAppConfiguration I should call `PopulateServiceStore(keyVaultUrl, keyVaultClient, keyStoreService);` so I still need to instantiate IKeyStoreService keystoreService...

Comment: Where do you assign the `_storeService` field?

Comment: in `Startup.cs`, inside `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) ` , I do `services.AddSingleton<IStoreService , KeyStoreService >();`

Comment: I got an idea, maybe I should reverse ConfigureWebHostDefaults with ConfigureAppConfiguration, I try that in case the order matters and let you know

Comment: It will not initialize your private static field.

Comment: Program.cs can also have a `.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter,
                      RequestSetOptionsStartupFilter>();
        });` trying this

Comment: AFAIK unless you write somewhere `_storeService  = ....` it will be null.